# Кнопка вставки изображения в редакторе

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток! Делаю свой визуальный редактор и столкнулся с проблемой - как реализовать кнопку вставки изображения?

Comment: Поподробнее можно? Путь к чему - `src` у `img`?

Comment: нужно выбрать изображение с компьютера и вставить его путь в scr у img

Comment: Т.е. нужно выбрать изображение с локального компа и вставить его в физивик как dataURL или сначала загрузить на сервер, а потом уже потом в редактор?

Comment: Во: @woland, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, помимо того, что диалог отобразить, так ещё и файлик куда-то залить придётся...

Посмотрите например, вот [это](http://fineuploader.com/#demo).

Comment: не придется - это редактор для моего движка, изображения будут лежать в определенной папке

Comment: Т.е. у Вас есть некая галерея готовых изображений? Отображайте диалог тогда с доступными изображениями...

Или проблема именно в отображении выбранного изображения в редакторе?

Comment: Вызываете модальное окно с выбором изображения. По клику на изображение вставляете в редактор нужный тег и закрываете модальное окно. Или вы хотите знать что-то другое?

Comment: я хочу узнать, как вызвать модальное окно

Comment: Вызывать окно для выбора файла можно только одним способом, чтобы пользователь кликнул по кнопке <input type="file"/>, скриптом это невозможно.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы код вставки выполнялся после того, как пользователь выбрал изображение?

Comment: Подписываетесь на событие change у этого инпута и в обработчике получаете список выбранных файлов `var files = event.target.files`, дальше читаете их как dataURL при помощи FileReader и вставляете в ваш визивиг. Но такой способ будет работать только в современных бразуерах, есть конечно заставить работать везде, но нужно ли оно вам?

Comment: Вот маленький пример накатал — http://jsfiddle.net/WFPNd/
За правильность работы с wysiwyg не ручаюсь, давно не возился.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы можно было сохранить url картинки? ато если вставить потом текст из бд, изображение не отображается